# using ms-appx-web in cordova for charge google map don't function

Tags: windows, cordova

I know that for charge a web context in a windows app I have to use an iframe with ms-appx-web, but while function normally in visual studio it doesn't function in cordova:

```
<iframe id="Map" src="ms-appx-web:///map.html" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
```

infact it give me two error:

APPHOST9623: The app couldn’t resolve ms-appx-web://pippo/map.html because of this error: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND.

APPHOST9613: The app couldn’t navigate to ms-appx-web://pippo/map.html because of this error: 80004005.

where pippo is this in config.xml file:

```
<widget id="pippo" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

i try to put no slash, 1 slash, 4 slash here: ms-appx-web:///map.html, but nothing work, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If your pages are located in the "/www" folder of your cordova project, you must use "ms-appx-web:///www/map.html" as the value for "src".